# Apartment gem migrations inside Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

I'm building a Rails Engine inside another rails app. The engine's rake tasks seem to get scoped to app:

```
# inside <app_root>/engines/engine_name
$ rake -T apartment
rake app:apartment:migrate       # Migrate all tenants
```

Whereas from the app's root:

```
#inside <app_root>/
$ rake -T apartment
rake apartment:migrate       # Migrate all tenants
```

My problem is when I run

```
# inside <app_root>/engines/engine_name
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

I get the following error:

> rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'apartment:migrate'

Seems like it should be calling the app:apartment:migrate task, but I'm not sure how to do this so I can test this engine on its own with RSpec

Comment: engine create this `--full` option?

Comment: yes, and I should note that the apartment gem is installed as a dependency of the engine.

Comment: maybe your gem is not installed for test environment?
please run 'RAILS_ENV=test rake -T apartment'

Comment: @edikgat, nope, shows up in all environments. inside the engine, I see `rake apartment:create` and `rake app:apartment:create`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a Rakefile for the engine here: `<app_root>/engines/engine_name/Rakefile`

Try adding this line to the bottom of it to load the rake tasks from the apartment gem:

```
load 'tasks/apartment.rake'
```

Comment: oh, nice, that seems to remove the error! will keep working on this today. so far, you're getting the bounty!